# How to read Twitter JSON?

Tags: php, twitter

I have a php document that deletes tweets. I want to get "http_code" from it, but nothing is working. Here's my code:

```
<?php

require_once('/twitter_files/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('/twitter_files/config.php');

$oauth_token = "****";
$oauth_token_secret = "****";

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
$content = $connection->delete('statuses/destroy/49628236694556672');

print_r($connection);
```

?>

With that print_r, I get a really long array that for some reason I can't read. Here's a snippet:

```
TwitterOAuth Object ( [http_code] => 404
```

How can I read it? I have tried json_decode, but I get errors.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that `print_r` output, we know that it is an instance of `TwitterOAuth` object. And the fact that it's object means that you can use it this way:

```
$connection->http_code
```